# Multiple screens on 2 computers, 1 computer and screen placed in center, Synergy

Tags: windows-xp, synergy

Is it possible to have 5 monitors connected to 1 computer, and have 1 monitor connected to another computer.
Like this:
PC1 - PC2 - PC1 - PC1 - PC1 - PC1

The issue is PC2, now I have to move the cursor to the left on the screen to the left to get to PC2, not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may have a look on the "links" section on the [Synergy configuration](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html)

> links
>
> [...] A link indicates which screen is adjacent in the given direction.
>
> Each side of a link can specify a range which defines a portion of an edge. A range on the direction is the portion of edge you can leave from while a range on the screen is the portion of edge you'll enter into. Ranges are optional and default to the entire edge. All ranges on a particular direction of a particular screen must not overlap.
>
> Example:

```
section: links
    moe:
        right        = larry
        up(50,100)   = curly(0,50)
    larry:
        left         = moe
        up(0,50)     = curly(50,100)
    curly:
        down(0,50)   = moe
        down(50,100) = larry(0,50)
end
```

[EDIT]

Ok, looked pretty obvious for me, but here you go :

```
section: links
  pc1:
    right(0,25)   = pc2
    left(25,75)   = pc2

  pc2:
    left          = pc1(0,25)
    right         = pc1(25,100)
```

I didn't tested-it but should be ok.

[/EDIT]

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt realy make me any smarter. Im  not sure how to transform this to vertical use, and how to get back to the PC1-screen to the left.

Comment: I added a code sample in the post.